# Congratulations Philipp 

Tags: discussion

Today, user [Philipp](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/21890/philipp) has reached the mark of 100k rep on gamedev.

With 21 questions, 1822 answers and ~3 million people reached over the last 8 years, that's a lot of help provided to hobbyist and professional game developers!

Congratulations, and thank you!

Comment: This is not a question. Come on man. :)

Comment: :P Maybe I should have used a question mark instead of a an exclamation mark at the end?

Comment: "Should we congratulate Philipp for 100k?" I'm sure you'd get a ton of YES answers. :)

Answer (score 14):

Thank you to all the people who found my content helpful enough to shower me with imaginary internet points. I hope you are all able to learn as much from me as I am able to learn myself by answering your questions. Also thanks to everyone who corrected me whenever I wrote nonsense. I always enjoy learning new tricks or getting my misconceptions corrected. Yes, seriously.

And now get back to work and create some cool games. See you again when I got to one million :)

Comment: _"And now get back to work"_ How did you know? Are you watching me??

Comment: Those points are not imaginary. They have a real world impact on both the storage bits in the database and in how people respond to your posts. :)